# How to "partial sync" code between two different git repositories?

Tags: git, synchronization

Suppose I have two git repos. At the beginning, the code of these two repos are the same. But then some of the commits to repo 1 will also be needed for repo 2, but some others not.

So for this situation, what is the best practice? How to just merge some commits from one repo to another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that REPO_1 is the URL to the first repository, and REPO_1 is the path to the second repository, run this in the second repository:

```
git remote add upstream REPO_1
git pull upstream
git cherry pick <hash_of_commit_to_select>...
```

Comment: another method is to use rebase.
has a discusstion in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845851/how-to-merge-code-from-branch1-to-branch2-but-excluding-some-commits.

Comment: Good point, I would recommend something like `git rebase -i upstream/master` in this case.